# Button in AngularJS grid not being disabled

Tags: angularjs

I have the following condition set in my grid-butto-listchecks.html file, but it doesn’t disable the row in the search results. Do you know what might be wrong? I know the controller that I'm using is the correct controller.

### HTML file

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
    <button title="Edit" type="button" class="btn grid-icon btn-xs btn-primary" ng-disabled="row.entity.ClaimStatusDescription=='Submit to Corporate GL'" ng-click="grid.appScope.gridCtrl.editRow(grid, row,row.entity.CheckDepositHeaderId)">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </button>
    <button title="View" type="button" class="btn grid-icon btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.gridCtrl.viewRow(grid, row)">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
    </button>
    <button title="Delete" type="button" class="btn grid-icon btn-xs btn-primary" ng-disabled="row.entity.ClaimStatusDescription=='Submit to Corporate GL'" ng-click="grid.appScope.gridCtrl.deleteRow(grid, row)">
        <i class="fa fa-trash  "></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

### Grid button field

```
{ field: 'CheckDepositHeaderId', name: '', cellTemplate: root + 'template/Check_Deposit/grid-butto-ListChecks.html', width: 90 },
```

You can see in the search results that I have that description coming out in the row (see image).
[image]

Comment: What happens if you output `row.entity.ClaimStatusDescription` in the html?

Comment: Verify the output of row.entity.ClaimStatusDescription and be sure to use === when doing comparisons.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-JavaScript-comparisons

Comment: It appears that when this feature is used in the html, that it removes the line and does not show up in the output which is fine by me.